# Ошибка при расписание таймера обратного отсчёта javascript

Tags: javascript

Задача - сделать таймер обратного отсчёта, но не простой, а автоматический с расписанием дат, например: отсчёт до определённой даты, прописанной в коде, который переходит в новый отсчёт до следующей прописанной даты. Вроде сделал всё правильно, но при переходе на новый отсчёт возникает ошибка. Так как не имею достаточного опыта, то не могу найти ошибку. Прошу помощи.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  clock.style.display = 'block';
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

// var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', schedule);

var schedule = [
    ['2018-05-01', '2018-05-02 13:36:00'],
    ['2018-05-02 13:36:01', '2018-05-09']
];

// iterate over each element in the schedule
for(var i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
  var startDate = schedule[i][0];
  var endDate = schedule[i][1];

  // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
  var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
  var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
  var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

  // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
  if(endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs ){
      initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate);
  }
}
```

работает [image: workred]

не работает [image: workred]
https://codepen.io/alivim/pen/RyVJKy

Comment: мы должны угадать в чем эта ошибка проявляется?

Comment: извиняюсь, что не указал - вместо времени Nan

Comment: Откровенно говоря проблем в коде несколько больше чем в смене дат ... что же касается конкретного вопроса, то причина в том, что у вас происходит вызов `initializeClock` вне цикла (42 строка), который и остается и передает (должен передавать) в функцию не массив, а двумерный массив с которым функция не знает что делать . Кроме того у вас этот вызов ещё и совершается до инициализации `schedule`.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, а есть возможность на скорую руку, помочь исправить сию проблему?